# Wordpress API uglify/JSON reference issue

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to refference certain items in the API but uglify and even my text editor are fighting me. For example:

```
post._embedded.author[0].avatar_urls.96
```

causes uglify to throw an error (probably because of the number). Here is another example:

```
post._embeded.wp:featuredmedia[0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url
```

Also causes issues for me (because of the colon).

How can I overcome this? Here is the full object I am trying to build:

```js
var postObject = {
  id: post.id,
  link: post.link,
  title: post.title.rendered,
  author: post._embedded.author[0].name,
  authorImage: post._embedded.author[0].avatar_urls .96,
  excerpt: post.excerpt.rendered,
  categories: post.categories, //add array of categories[]
  featuredImage: post._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this one out!

```
post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url
```

I was unaware of the bracket notations!